# UI-Select not showing selected option

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to display some data in a select box using UI-Select.
It shows the options, but when I select one of them my input just still blank.

Here is my json

```
{
  "listaCecProduto": [
    {
      "aplicacaoProduto": "30",
      "cecs": [
       {
     "idCec": 339,
     "nome": "RH - 16584665699425 - 30 - Cultura",
     "ordemExibicao": 1,
     "padrao": false
    }
  ]
},
{
  "aplicacaoProduto": "28",
  "cecs": [
    {
     "idCec": 338,
     "nome": "RH - 16584665699425 - 28 - Auto (VeÃ culo",
     "ordemExibicao": 1,
     "padrao": false
    }
   ]
  }
 ]
}
```

and all my data is in a variable named cec.lista

```
for (var i in response.data.listaCecProduto) {
    $scope.cec.lista.push(response.data.listaCecProduto[i]);
    console.log("lista", $scope.cec.lista);
  }
```

and this is my template:

```
<ui-select id="cec_config_{{item.produto.codigo}}" ng-model="cec.item" theme="selectize" reset-search-input="true" title="Selecione">

    <ui-select-match placeholder="Selecione">
        {{ $select.selected.nome }}
    </ui-select-match>

    <ui-select-choices repeat="cec in cec.lista">
         <div ng-if="cec.aplicacaoProduto  == item.produto.codigo">
            <div class="wrapper" ng-repeat="i in cec.cecs">
                <span ng-bind-html="i.nome | highlight: $select.search"></span>
                 <small ng-bind-html="i.idCec | highlight: $select.search"></small>
             </div>  
         </div>
      </ui-select-choices>
    </ui-select>
```

I tried few solutions, but none of them worked. Any idea whats wrong ?

Comment: Do you get the expected data when you log `$scope.cec.lista`?

Comment: Also this would be much easier to try and debug if you provided a working (as-is) plunkr or fiddle.

Comment: @ben yes, i get the expected data